# calling mathematica from.net

Tags: c#, wolfram-mathematica

I am calling Mathematica from Visual Studio using C#. 
I am facing error -

> "error code: 1012. protocol unavailable".

I am using Windows forms to fetch data from a device and sending it to Mathematica tool and do some processing and need to return the processed data back to Windows forms UI. Please see code below.

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

            {

            // This launches the Mathematica kernel:
            IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();

            ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();

            // Now compute 2+2 

            string result = ml.EvaluateToOutputForm("2+2", 0);
            Console.WriteLine("2 + 2 = " + result);

            ml.Close();

            // Wait for user to close window.
            Console.WriteLine("Press Return to exit...");
            Console.Read();

           }
```

Comment: Please add your code see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may find some help in the solution here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156680/how-to-control-which-version-of-mathematica-net-link-uses